# Upload image to server using http POST request

Tags: ios, http, blackberry, httprequest, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload image to server but it was not correctly uploading getting http error 415 and when i tried to upload in blackberry it is uploading correctly can any one tell me what i missed here is the code for BB and ios

Code for iOS

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 90); /// convert image in NSData
NSString *urlString = @"http://api.Domain.com:8080/upImg/"; // your url
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"pic"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

// now lets make the connection to the web
 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Code in BB:

```
httpConnection = MakeUrl.returnUrl(url);
httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

 httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
  HttpProtocolConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux "+ "i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20061201 Firefox/2.0.0.6 (Ubuntu-feisty)");
 httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xml,"+ "application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/jpg,*/*;q=0.5");
 httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  URLEncodedPostData _postData = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8",false);
 _postData.append("pic", postData);
OutputStream os = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
os.write(_postData.getBytes());
os.flush();
```

Comment: Mybe give details about your context. i understand it is on blackberry, but give more details about your setup, and connection setting to get an answer faster. Best

Comment: The BlackBerry code works properly, but the iOS code returns a 415 error?